# Bad practice - Class defines compareTo(...) and uses Object.equals()

Tags: java, sonarqube

Wondering what needs to be done for listed method

```
 public final int compareTo(final FieldDTO o) {
        return o.available.compareTo(this.available);
```

its throwing exception on line 2 stating 
 Bad practice - Class defines compareTo(...) and uses Object.equals()     16 days
field defines compareTo(FieldDTO) and uses Object.equals()

Not sure how should i handle this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is really throwing an Exception? Or is it just a warning (maybe by findBugs)?

Comment: FieldDTO seems to be an internal class of your project, ask this question for who created it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you define `compareTo` you should at least define `equals`

```
boolean equals(it) { 
  return compareTo(it) == 0; 
}
```

otherwise you will get strange problems when you put your object in `Map`s and `Set`s. It is generally good practice to also define `hashCode`.

Answer (score 8):

you need to override Object class equals() and hashCode() methods.
Use IDE generated code for these, it will pull all the Object attributes and creates method for you.

On eclipse IDE:

1. Right click on the class
2. Select Source
3. Generate hashCode() and equals()...

Answer (score 7):

This is the documentation from [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#EQ_COMPARETO_USE_OBJECT_EQUALS):

> Eq: Class defines compareTo(...) and uses Object.equals()
>   (EQ_COMPARETO_USE_OBJECT_EQUALS)
>
> This class defines a compareTo(...) method but inherits its equals()
>   method from java.lang.Object. Generally, the value of compareTo should
>   return zero if and only if equals returns true. If this is violated,
>   weird and unpredictable failures will occur in classes such as
>   PriorityQueue. In Java 5 the PriorityQueue.remove method uses the
>   compareTo method, while in Java 6 it uses the equals method.
>
> From the JavaDoc for the compareTo method in the Comparable interface:
>
> It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that
>   (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any class
>   that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition
>   should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note:
>   this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."

So it seems you need to implement the `equals` method thus overriding the default implementation from `Object`.