# Findbugs bug? "defines compareTo() and uses Object.equals()"

Tags: findbugs, compareto

I'm getting the following Findbugs error, similar to the one outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701047/bad-practice-class-defines-compareto-and-uses-object-equals):

> This class defines a compareTo(...) method but inherits its equals()
>   method from java.lang.Object.

for this method inside of my class:

```
Public class MyClass {

    public int getCost() { ... }

  @Override
    public final int compareTo(MyClass other) {
      return Integer.compare(this.getCost(), other.getCost());
    }
}
```

And I think that isn't quite true - `Integer.compare` is being used, which, according to the API:

> the value 0 if x == y; a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value
>   greater than 0 if x > y

So, in attempt to circumvent the error, I tried to write it manually, and got the same error:

```
public class MyClass {

  public int getCost() { ... }

  public final int compareTo(Myclass other) {
      if (this.finalCost < other.getFinalCost()) {
        return 1;
      } else if (this.getCost() > other.getCost() ) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
  }
```

Now, I'm not even defining or using an `equals()` method at all. Is this a FindBugs bug?

Also, many suggestions I read say to implement your own equals method (which I get) but also your own hash... which I don't understand why. Any elaboration would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad practice - Class defines compareTo(...) and uses Object.equals()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701047/bad-practice-class-defines-compareto-and-uses-object-equals)

Comment: Similar situation but different question. I'm not necessarily asking how to fix this as your linked question does (and which I did post in my original answer as well), but if the FindBugs assessment is incorrect. Or, if it is correct, how that's true when the Java API seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: The FindBugs assessment is correct, as explained in the answers to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the compareTo is overridden in this class but the implementation of the equals is inherited from Object class, thus uses different logic.
This might lead to a situation where compareTo() returns 0, but equals() returns false;